trying to launch browser in eclipse selenium IDE written correct code but web page is not loading getting multiple error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.(ClientConfig.java:33)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:83)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:51)
at Newproject/selenium.selenium_Intro.main(selenium_Intro.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
... 4 more
trying to load webpage through selenium
getting below erroe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.(ClientConfig.java:33)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:83)
at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:51)
at Newproject/selenium.selenium_Intro.main(selenium_Intro.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.
